# how i can sort user by role in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm running Rocket Chat system in developer version and I need to sort users by role to keep top levels like ( admin / owner / moderator) in the top list, not by online status because the default sort is

```
    // show online users first.
    // sortBy is stable, so we can do this
    users = _.sortBy(users, u => u.status == null);
```

I need to change this code to sort by role level
and this example for user data in users.json

```
"type" : "user", 
"status" : "offline", 
"active" : true, 
"name" : "Super", 
"_updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-05-16T15:10:30.559+0000"), 
"roles" : [
    "admin"
]
```

in this screenshot user with red is admin and in black is member and i need to move admin in top
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us6Zw.png)

Comment: you will have to define how you want to sort by role, eg assigning value to the role so you can compare it.

Comment: im not expert in nodejs but this line  ( users = _.sortBy(users, u => u.status == null); ) list my users with online status and i need to change it to sort by top levels to keep admin in top list

Comment: You can just use the `Array.prototype.sort()` method. You can define any kind of comparison you like.

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/mcuzr/) it may give you a clue...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, sorting is handled by providing a comparer function. This function simply takes two objects, A and B, and determines their relative placement. You as the programmer decide the logic used to determine the ordering.

Here's an example based on your description.

```
const roleComparer = (a, b) => {
  if (a.roles.includes('admin') && !b.roles.includes('admin')) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (b.roles.includes('admin') && !a.roles.includes('admin')) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

To sort, you simply pass it into the Array.prototype.sort() method as the argument:

```
users = users.sort(roleComparer);
```

What the sort() method does is it walks through the array one index at a time, and applies the comparer function you provide. It compares the current index (argument a) with the next one (argument b). If it returns 1, a is greater. If -1, less. If 0, they're equal.

This is not unique to javascript, but is how sorting/comparing is handled in many languages.